# Flutter add icon on border of container

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a simple card of address i need to place an icon on end of the container on between line

My code

```
                                Container(
                                    width: double.infinity,
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15.0),
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                                      border: Border.all(
                                        color: dateindex == index
                                            ? Theme.of(context).primaryColor
                                            : Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                                        width: dateindex == index ? 2.0 : 1.0,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    child: Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        Text(
                                            showAddress
                                                ? address['Address'][index]
                                                    ['Address']
                                                : '...',
                                            style: Theme.of(context)
                                                .textTheme
                                                .headline4),
                                        SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                                        Text(
                                            showAddress
                                                ? address['Address'][index]
                                                    ['StreetName']
                                                : '...',
                                            style: Theme.of(context)
                                                .textTheme
                                                .headline5),
                                        
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  )
```

It look like this right now

[image]

I have a marker in the screenshot here I need an icon. Can anyone please tell how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You won't require these code just add a ListTile
and pass 2 icon's in column and pass it in trailing
Here's an example:-

```
title: Text('your 2 bold lines'),
subtitle:Text('your 2 bold lines next semi visible lines'),
trailing:Column(children<Widget>:[
Icon(),
Icon(),],),)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess u want location Icon at end of container and it will align centre of these lines?

You can follow this approach

```
Row(
children:[Column(children:[Put you address widget]),Column(children:[Icon])])
```

or  You can use `ListTile()`

Give your icon a mainaxis alignment make it center.